# how to keep my style of page in landscape?

Tags: pdftex, landscape

I want to create a landscape page anywhere in the document and to maintain the style of my document also change the margin on these pages I need to create another page style?

```
\documentclass[oneside,spanish,10pt,a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{anysize}
\marginsize{3cm}{2cm}{2cm}{2cm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{color} 
\definecolor{yourcolor}{HTML}{6C17A1}
\makechapterstyle{mystyle}{%
\chapterstyle{default}
\renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\normalfont\Huge\sffamily\bfseries}
\renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\huge\sffamily\itshape\color{yourcolor}}
\settowidth{\chapindent}{\chapnumfont 111}
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstart}{}
\renewcommand*{\chapnamefont}{\hfill\color{yourcolor}\normalfont\Huge\sffamily\bfseries}
\renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={([yshift=-.6ex]current bounding box.center)}]
\node[fill=yourcolor,circle,text=white] {\thechapter};
\end{tikzpicture}\\[1ex]
\hrule height 1.5pt}
\renewcommand*{\printchaptertitle}[1]{%
{\chaptitlefont ##1}}
}
%------------------

\makepagestyle{myruled}
\makeheadfootruleprefix{myruled}{\color{yourcolor}}{\color{yourcolor}}
\makeheadrule{myruled}{\textwidth}{1.5pt}
\makefootrule{myruled}{\textwidth}{1.5pt}{\footruleskip}
\makeevenhead{myruled}{}{\small\itshape\leftmark}{}
\makeoddhead{myruled}{}{\small\itshape\rightmark}{}
\makeevenfoot{myruled}{\color{yourcolor}\small\thepage}{}{} 
\makeoddfoot{myruled}{}{}{\color{yourcolor}\small\thepage}
\makeatletter % because of \@chapapp
\makepsmarks{myruled}{
\nouppercaseheads
\createmark{chapter}{both}{shownumber}{\color{yourcolor}\@chapapp\ }{\color{yourcolor}. \ }
\createmark{section}{right}{shownumber}{\color{yourcolor}}{\color{yourcolor}. \ }
\createmark{subsection}{right}{shownumber}{\color{yourcolor}}{. \ }
\createmark{subsubsection}{right}{shownumber}{\color{yourcolor}}{. \ }
\createplainmark{toc}{both}{\contentsname}
\createplainmark{lof}{both}{\listfigurename}
\createplainmark{lot}{both}{\listtablename}
\createplainmark{bib}{both}{\bibname}
\createplainmark{index}{both}{\indexname}
\createplainmark{glossary}{both}{\glossaryname}
}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{myruled}
\chapterstyle{mystyle}    
%use new chapter style



\begin{document}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} 
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3} 
\chapter{some text}
\section{some text}
\lipsum[1-20]
\subsection{some text}
\lipsum
\subsubsection{some text}
\lipsum
{
\newpage
\begin{landscape}
\lipsum
\end{landscape}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]